# Find solutions for $t$ in $y = \sin^2(t)-\cos(t)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Im trying to find the possible solutions for $t$ if $y = 0$:

$$y = \sin^2(t)-\cos(t)$$

How should I proceed? Thanks!

Or better said, how can I rewrite $\sin^2(t)$ so that I can short it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Use $$\sin^2 t = 1 - \cos^2 t$$

$$\sin^2(t)-\cos(t) = 0 \iff (1 - \cos^2 t ) - \cos t = 0 \iff \cos^2 t + \cos t 
- 1 = 0$$
You have a quadratic in $\cos t$. Put $x = \cos t$, and see if you can solve the resulting quadratic equation. If not, no solutions exist.

Comment: Can you explain it a little bit further im stuck! Thanks!

Comment: Substitute $\cos t = x \implies \;\;x^2 + x - 1 = 0.\;$ Now use the quadratic formula, if you need, to solve for $x$. Are there any real-valued solutions?

Comment: Ah ok i see! Thanks! But i have on more little question. Is it possible to write the normal $sin(x)$ as some $cos(x)$ as you did in your example with $sin^2(x)$? Thanks

Comment: $\sin x = \pm \sqrt{1 - \cos^2 x}$. ;-)

Comment: And $cos^2(x)$? Thanks!

Comment: You'll want to become familiar with the notation. $\cos^2 x = (\cos x)^2$, just as $\sin^2 x = (\sin x)^2$. It's simply "shorthand".

Comment: In trigonometric equations of this sort, the trigonometric function in the linear term determines which trig function you want to set the quadratic term in.  The Pythagorean Theorem gives us a relation between $ \ \sin^2 x \ \text{and} \ \cos^2 x \ $ (or $ \ \tan^2 x \ \text{and} \ \sec^2 x \ $ or $ \ \cot^2 x \ \text{and} \ \csc^2 x \ ) . $  Because the linear term would have to be re-written involving a square-root of a function, we want to _avoid_ that in working for solutions to these quadratic polynomials.  So, for your problem, we want to express the terms entirely using cosines.

Answer (score 1):

$\sin^2 t = \cos t$. Trigonometric algebra is similar to that of regular algebra: You typically want single variable equations, and we can use trigonometric identities to achieve that. In particular, $\sin^2 t = 1 - \cos^2 t$. $$1 - \cos^2 t = \cos t$$

Let $\cos t = x$

$$1 - x^2 = x$$

$$x^2 + x - 1 = 0$$

$$x = \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$$

For $t \in \mathbb{R}$, $\cos t \in [-1, 1]$, so the only real solution is $\cos^{-1} (\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}) \approx \pm 0.905 + 2k\pi$